# Using Late Bound Assemblies with Xamarin for iOS

Tags: ios, servicestack, xamarin

I'm trying to port one of my iOS apps from the Mono versions of the
ServiceStack.Text libraries to the PCL versions for JSON
serialization/deserialization.

I have the libraries working in a regular Windows console application. When trying to port this into the iOS application, I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception from on the ServiceStack extension method classes. The error message is a red herring; the true error is getting swollowed by a try/catch.

The static constructor in ServiceStack.Text.PCL.PclExport is doing late binding for a
platform specific DLL and can't find that DLL. The build log bears out that the
Client, Interface, and Pcl libraries aren't being packaged with the .app file even though the reference are included at the project level.

I've been able to reproduce this in a basic iOS Hello World application. If I
add a line of code that references a method in the Pcl DLL, the three missing
libraries are copied. However, I'm still getting the same "Object reference not
set to an instance of an object" error.

I suspect that this is caused by the fact the Xamarin compiler doesn't translate the DLLs into iOS binaries unless they are actually used, and since they're late bound, it doesn't know they're used and so ignores them.

Comment: This is probably a better question for Xamarin.

Comment: We've already submitted a bug. The point of this question is to see if anybody has a workaround or knows how to force the Xamarin compiler to translate these DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think late binding was legal under the licensing on at actual iPhone? doesn't the link merge everything into one exe?

[See the Xamarin Linker Docs](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/) try the -nolinkaway option.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment, although I too thought that late binding DLL's on an iPhone was not allowed.  But that problem wouldn't show up until Apple reviewed the app and rejected it, right?

Comment: not if the linking merges everything. I think when using the emulator you can switch the merging off.

Comment: I tried the nolinkaway option, but it didn't seem to do the trick.